# Angular Nx Nrwl - Cannot parse tsconfig.base.json: PropertyNameExpected in JSON when try to create a new lib

Tags: json, angular, angularjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Im getting this error

```
Cannot parse tsconfig.base.json: PropertyNameExpected in JSON at position 891
```

when i run `nx g @nrwl\angular:lib libName` on CLI

my tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@admin-env/*": ["apps/admin/src/environments/*"],
      "@admin/*": ["apps/admin/src/app/*"],
      "@portal-env/*": ["apps/portal/src/environments/*"],
      "@portal/*": ["apps/portal/src/app/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

When i run i'm getting the error `Cannot parse tsconfig.base.json: PropertyNameExpected in JSON at position 891`.

The same happens when i try to run `npx nx g @nrwl/angular:lib libName` or `nx g @nrwl/angular:lib`

I'm usin VScode to write code, and there is no warning (lint) of error in `tsconfig.base.json`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I got this error when there was a comma ',' at the end of the `paths` list.

```
"@portal/*": ["apps/portal/src/app/*"],  <<< REMOVE this comma
```

Comment: Yes - spent hours looking for solution, it was this simple fix. Thanks

Comment: I was missing commas in the tsconfig.base.json,

Comment: heroes not always wear capes!!